# Where is a good place for a code review?

Tags: c++, gtk, pcap

A few colleagues and I created a simple packet capturing application based on libpcap, GTK+ and sqlite as a project for a Networks Engineering course at our university. While it (mostly) works, I am trying to improve my programming skills and would appreciate it if members of the community could look at what we've put together.

Is this a good place to ask for such a review? If not, what are good sites I can throw this question up on? The source code is hosted by Google Code (http://code.google.com/p/nbfm-sniffer) and an executable is available for download (Windows only, though it does compile on Linux and should compile on OS X Leopard as well provided one has gtk+ SDK installed).

Thanks, everyone!

-Carlos Nunez

UPDATE: Thanks for the great feedback, everyone. The code is completely open-source and modifiable (licensed under Apache License 2.0). I was hoping to get more holistic feedback, considering that my postings would still be very lengthy.

Comment: Think about what some of your worse problems where, post your solution, and ask for input.  Asking for review of a complete project may not get the attention you desire.

Comment: +1 because you asked before posting.

Comment: You've written a lot of code and few people who have the skills would be willing to review your project.  That said, you may have some luck with getting specific small chunks reviewed.

Comment: One useful tool is to think about the harder problems you solved, then find open source programs that solve the same problem, and review how they did it.  If there is another good packet capturing out there that is open source, that'd be a good place to start.

Comment: Samuel,
I know it's a bulky project, but again, I was hoping to get feedback related to the project as a whole rather than certain subsections of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might get some mileage by posting the code out in the public space (through github or some other open-posting forum), putting a link here on SO, and seeing what happens.

You could also make it an open-source project, and see if people find it and use it.

Probably your best bet is to talk to your prof/classmates, find some professional programmers willing to devote their time, and have them review the code.  Like American Idol-esque judging, but for your software...

Answer (score 1):

As sheepsimulator mentioned, GitHub is good.  I would also recommend posting your project on [SourceForge.net](http://sourceforge.net) and/or [FreshMeat.net](http://freshmeat.net).  Both are active developer communities where people often peruse projects like yours.  The best thing for your code would be if someone found it useful and decided to extend it.  Then, you'd probably end up with plenty of bug fixes and constructive criticism.

Comment: Thanks, Eric! I was thinking Google Code was a good place for this kind of community interaction, but I'll host it on SourceForge as well.

Answer (score 0):

As @Noah states, this is not the site for code review. You may present problems and what you did to overcome those problems, asking if a given solution would be the best.

I found a neat little website that might be what you are looking for: [Cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/)